# WPA pre-shared key format in linux and macintosh

Tags: osx, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm temporarily in a situation where the wifi network I need to use is implemented using Macintosh equipment. They have encoded their network using WPA and TKIP. I can't seem to get onto their network and I *think* I've tracked the problem down to the pre-shared key format. When others (using Macs) enter the PSK into thier Mac interface thing, they use a 13 digit code that is all integers [0-9], e.g. `0123456789123`. In my `wpa1.conf` file, which is used by `wpa_supplicant` to configure `iwconfig`, I have a line in the network block:

```
psk="0123456789123"
```

I *think* that I should be entering a hex string (yes, I know this *could* be a hex string already). **Does anyone here have any experience with Mac's UI concerning the format psk's are entered in,  and whether I need to change them into hex to use a psk in my linux (slackware 13.1)?**

Note that my wireless setup works fine in other environments that don't use WPA or a pre-shared key which indicates that the hardware and firmware are ok.

Comment: WPA PSK does not have the same problem as WEP where various vendors tried to make it easier to type in the WEP HEX key.  WPA PSK defines a standard method to convert a passphrase of US-ASCII printable characters into a 64 character HEX string.  If the passphrase entered in is less than 64 characters, it's a passphrase as US-ASCII.  They would have to have exactly 64 characters to make it a Hex key.  Look at the section under Security and Insecurity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access

Comment: @penguin359 - so what are you saying? that the method I use to enter the psk is ok and my problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Yes.  With WEP there were problems about using password vs. hex key as well as different incompatible password schemes.  That doesn't happen with WPA PSK.

Comment: Can you post any output from running wpa_supplicant manually?

Comment: Any change if you leave off the quotes?